# How to set Button style resource programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to set button style programmatically. Reason for that is I have CustomView containing `Button`. I send style id to my CustomView using custom parameter inside `<declare-styleable>`. Now I need to set button style for only `Button` not whole view in my CustomView.

CustomView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorText"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

CustomView in my code:

```
<myproject.CustomView
                    android:id="@+id/btn"
                    app:progressColor="@color/colorText"
                    app:l_buttonText="@string/text"
                    app:l_buttonStyle="@style/dialog_outlined"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />
```

What I want to achieve is to set style for Button only (value obtained from `app:l_buttonStyle`) But I have to do this programmatically, because if I set style in XML it will be applied to `FrameLayout` as a root view. Here is function to init parts of my CustomView

```
 private fun init(context: Context) {
        //Init default values
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.loading_button, this)
        button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        progressBar?.setGone()

        //Now I need to set style for my inflated Button from XML layout
    }
```

Comment: If your layout contains only 2 views it will be easier to create all of them in code and when creating use the style which you received via styleable.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using this layout in multiple places in my code. That means I will have to implement progress show/hide and button text show/hide in every single part of my code where this button is used. This way I wanted to call only one function button?.setloading(boolean).

Comment: I am not sure that i understand you correctly. You have already created custom view that in init part will set the style. Equivalently you can not use `        View.inflate(context, R.layout.loading_button, this)` in init but create Button and Progress there as normal view and add it using addView method, and in this situation you will be able to create button with your style

Comment: Ah ok. Yes my CustomView class extends FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

The views in custom view has to be created programmatically and at the time of initializing the view custom style has to be applied. Once the view is initialized, style cannot be set.

```
val button = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Button(this, null, 0, R.style.BtnStyle)
    } else {
        var themeWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.BtnStyle)
        Button(themeWrapper, null, 0)
    }
```